# SQL Statement does not insert the required value to table column

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I'm inserting some values to a table using a sql statement. All the values get inserted, except the 'qty' column. When I do an echo for sql statement, it shows the value has been assigned to the sql statement. Table column data type is INT. Can anyone help me to spot the problem?

```
$it_code = $_POST['id']; 

//Prompt user to enter required qty
echo '<script>'; 
echo 'var qty = prompt("Enter Qty", "");';
echo '</script>';

//Get the item details from item table
$sqlString = "Select * from items where it_code='".$it_code."'";
$objItem = new Allfunctions;
$result = $objItem->retriveData($sqlString);

//Get the selected qty from java script to php variable
$qty = "<script>document.writeln(qty);</script>";
$user_id =$_SESSION['user_id'];  

//Insert to orders table
$sqlStringInsert = "INSERT INTO orders(user_id,it_code,qty,status,tr_timestamp) VALUES ('$user_id','$it_code','$qty','PENDING',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())";
echo $sqlStringInsert;
$objItem->addToTable($sqlStringInsert,'Succsessfully added.','Error adding'); // This is a custom built method to insert data in to a table by taking the sql statement as the parameter
```

Following is the sql statement generated,
[image]

Following is the table data. Qty is always 0 eventhood the sql statement had a value at qty column.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no way that's the SQL statement that's getting echoed by that script.  Currently you show $qty as being assigned to a string of HTML right before being injected into $sqlStringInsert.  Are you sure you're showing the actual output of the script here?

Comment: Can you please post the sql statement as text instead of a picture. Then we could use it and work with it in order to try to help you

Comment: INSERT INTO orders(user_id,it_code,qty,status,tr_timestamp) VALUES ('1','s0015','10 ','PENDING',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())

Comment: Above is the value echoed by php for the variable '$sqlStringInsert'

Comment: Strange, the resulting query looks correct. Did you check: a.) when executing the query are there any errors? b.) are there any triggers on the table? A trigger could theoretically change the value to 0.

Comment: There are no triggers in the table. All other values get inserted except qty and I don't get any errors either. I have a suspicion that this is because I'm getting the value from java script. Could it be the reason?

Comment: if you suspect that javascript has an influence please add the tag javascript to the question. You could try to use [mysql query profiler](https://web.archive.org/web/20110609054749/http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html)

Comment: You can't embed javascript inside PHP!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Obligatory warning

The code as you have shown it should not be used in production as it is vulnerable to [SQL-injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Preventing this is [well covered on this site in other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496).

## Answer

The issue is that the value of `$qty` you are injecting into your SQL is the string `"<script>document.writeln(qty);</script>"`.  You just can't see it because you are likely echoing it out to the browser to test it.

Wrap your echoing of the SQL statement in a call to `htmlentities()` ([docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)) to see what's actually happening.

Depending on the version and settings, MySQL is very forgiving of bad data being injected to a column.  In this case, it sees a string of text being inserted to a numeric column, and just truncates it to 0.  See this in action here:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Foo (
  Id INT,
  Qty INT
 );
 
INSERT INTO Foo(Id, Qty) VALUES (1, 'a string of text');

SELECT * FROM Foo; -- returns a row (1, 0)
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dEoaYGEyXEjs6ocVBwyyyr/1

Comment: Sounds like this is the problem. Wondering, why the insert is partially working, shouldn't it throw an error?

Comment: @Peter206, see my edits.  TL;DR; likely not unless you have certain SQL modes enabled.

Comment: Agreed, especially about the output not showing.  This can be very tricky for new people because those script tags wont show up in HTML output.